# Updating progress bar based on segment event

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

I am trying to update the state of a progress bar depending on where I click within a segment.

I have a function which returns the normalised relative position of the click within the segment (see `getMousePos` below), and I think it works correctly by looking at console outputs.

Currently the progress-bar does not change at all, and I don't understand why. There are no errors that I can see in the console, and the callback responsible for doing the update correctly outputs the clicked position with `console.log`.

Here is the smallest example I could come up with, which reproduces this error:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.7/semantic.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.7/semantic.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="foo:s" class="ui segment" style="height:300px">
    </div>
    <div id="foo:p" class="ui progress">
        <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        /**
         * Returns normalised x and y position (between 0 and 1) of mouse pointer, 
         * relative to top-left corner of input DOM element.
         */
        function getMousePos(elm, evt) {
            var rect = elm.getBoundingClientRect();
            return {
                x: (evt.clientX - rect.left) / (rect.right - rect.left),
                y: (evt.clientY - rect.top) / (rect.bottom - rect.top)
            };
        }

        // Initialise progressbar
        $('#foo:p').progress();

        // Bind click events to progress bar state
        document
            .getElementById('foo:s')
            .addEventListener("click", function(evt) {

                var pos = getMousePos(this, evt);
                console.log(pos);

                $('#foo:p').progress({
                    percent: Math.floor(100 * pos.x)
                });

            });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

You can see it running on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/sheljohn/pen/rjPaOp?editors=1001).

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.7/semantic.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.7/semantic.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="foo_s" class="ui segment" style="height:300px">
    </div>
    <div id="foo_p" class="ui progress">
        <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        /**
         * Returns normalised x and y position (between 0 and 1) of mouse pointer, 
         * relative to top-left corner of input DOM element.
         */
        function getMousePos(elm, evt) {
            var rect = elm.getBoundingClientRect();
            return {
                x: (evt.clientX - rect.left) / (rect.right - rect.left),
                y: (evt.clientY - rect.top) / (rect.bottom - rect.top)
            };
        }

        // Initialise progressbar
        $('#foo_p').progress();

        // Bind click events to progress bar state
        document
            .getElementById('foo_s')
            .addEventListener("click", function(evt) {

                var pos = getMousePos(this, evt);
                console.log(pos);

                $('#foo_p').progress({
                    percent: Math.floor(100 * pos.x)
                });

            });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

The Progress bar is a jquery-ui element, so you need to include support for that.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

To get it to work in your codepen, I also had to rename your 'foo:' names with 'foo_'.

I don't know if the colon in IDS is valid HTML or not.

Comment: Ha, thanks a lot, I thought I read somewhere that colons were allowed in IDs, but that must have been wrong. The jquery UI libs don't seem to be necessary though.

Comment: If you could please update your answer to focus on the fact that the IDs were incorrect, and not that the jQuery UI libraries were needed, I would be happy to mark you as the answer.